# mysqli uses much more memory than mysql, exhausts memory_limit

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-5.6

I am trying to update an old app that is currently still using `mysql` functions. Unfortunately, with `mysqli`, the app runs out of memory in cases where `mysql` never did (and, honestly, it shouldn't). With `mysql`, the process gets up to maybe 50 MB, which suggests it's allocating 8-15 MB on top of the idle set size. With `mysqli`, it exhausts the limit (128) and even hit 256 MB without blinking (just loading the index page). Something isn't right. I am receiving this error when I switch to `mysqli`:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 9072253 bytes)

The "tried to allocate" amount of bytes changes every time, it's not constant. The app does have an abstraction class, so I started by gutting that and replacing the calls with a `mysqli` instance (OOP, not procedural). Rewriting all the queries will take a long time and isn't feasible resource-wise right now. I do have `mysqlnd` installed. This is currently on PHP 5.6.30.

The code has changed a lot through troubleshooting, but here is one incarnation of the `query` method:

```
$result = $connection->query($sql);
$data = Array();
$i = 0;
while ($r = $result->fetch_assoc())
    $data[$i++] = $r;

$ret = new stdClass();
$ret ->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : Array();
$ret ->rows = $data;
$ret ->num_rows = $i;

$result->free();
unset($data);
return $ret ;
```

I've tried using `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` and a few different ways of iterating/gathering the query results, like `fetch_all`, reference assignment, no `while` loop, but none of it helped.

My next step would probably be to try a PDO instance instead...

Comment: The question is missing crucial information: What's the query you're executing and how many rows / columns(types/sizes) are you expecting in return?

Comment: If you are using glob i suggest to check into http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php. I've came up with the same error when updating my code and this function saved the day on big data sets. Ir is knowed to use more computing ressources but also free some memory.

Comment: Are you sure mysqli is the one consuming the memory? Seems like a php memory leak to me

Comment: Yes, to try PDO would be an excellent idea

Comment: @YourCommonSense This isn't a duplicate of that as I'm not using any longtext columns, which is why I mentioned the allocation size.

Comment: @ccKep This code is used to execute all queries in the app. The queries are identical between `mysql` and `mysqli`, so I wouldn't expect such a huge difference in memory usage.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier From what I read, store result is the default `query` uses. I've tried both store_result and use_result and there wasn't any difference.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have longblob or not, the problem is the same: wrong allocation. you already were thinking of PDO which is batter than mysqli in many ways anyway - so you have a sign

Comment: @Theo I'm not sure that it's `mysqli` using the memory versus some other part of PHP, not sure how to test that. All I "know" is what I observed, that it uses a lot more memory when using `mysqli` then it does when using `mysql`...

Comment: Might not be much but maybe http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stat.php can help you see what's going on. If you have root access to your host you can also use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.debug.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.dump-debug-info.php (depends on you build [aka installation] too)

Comment: Same exact problem with PDO...